# Erro na persistence.xml ao conectar banco oracle

Tags: java, hibernate, oracle, persistência

Tenho este arquivo para realizar a persistência de banco oracle. Porém não conectar!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd" version="2.0">
   <persistence-unit name="app_crud_cliente">
      <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
      <class>br.com.model.ClienteModel</class>
      <properties>
         <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
         <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/bd_cliente" />
         <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="DBA" />
         <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="DBA" />
         <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect" />
      </properties>
   </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Comment: A sua url de conexão, driver e o dialect do hibernate fazem referência ao MySQL.
Segue um link que pode te ajudar: [http://www.guj.com.br/t/resolvido-configuracao-arquivo-persistence-xml-oracle/295362](http://www.guj.com.br/t/resolvido-configuracao-arquivo-persistence-xml-oracle/295362)

Comment: como instalar o jdbc do oracle ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conforme citado nos comentários, suas configurações utilizam o MySQL e não o Oracle.

Para utilizar o Oracle faça:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd" version="2.0">
   <persistence-unit name="app_crud_cliente">
      <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
      <class>br.com.model.ClienteModel</class>
      <properties>
         <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"/>
         <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@ip:porta/nome-da-instancia" />
         <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="DBA" />
         <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="DBA" />
         <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect"/>
      </properties>
   </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Obs: o dialeto pode mudar dependendo da sua versão do Oracle.

Comment: estou baixando a versão : ojdbc14.jar!